# Local cURL in PHP: what route is used?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, curl

Suppose server A, via domain A, hosts a website.

Suppose server A, via domain B, also hosts a web service.

The website calls this web service via a PHP/cURL-based API.

**Question:** even though they live on the same physical server, am I right in thinking the request goes out to the ether and back in, because the domains are different, or does cURL/something have some way of "knowing" it's really the same server, and so there's no reason to go outside?

Comment: Well it is a cURL question insofar as the technique depends on cURL and it would be perfectly reasonable to suppose that the answer depended on the workings of cURL. If that's not the case, fine, but it's a little silly to say it's "not really a cURL question."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the request leaves the server no matter what since it's over http - there's no way of it knowing weather the two resources are on the same server or not. You could rip through all the source code but I don't think it would do that - usually if you want to call a resource on the same server you can use absolute file paths as opposed to http requests.

curl source:
[curl source](https://github.com/bagder/curl)

Comment: ... not if the IP addresses are hosted by the same machine

Comment: Yes the same thought occurred to me after I posted the question. If all cURL has to go on is a domain, it has no way of knowing what server that's associated with without a trip out to the domain registry.  So it's kind of obvious when you think of it that way. Calling the request by IP would probably ensure it went locally, but most hosts don't allow HTTP via IP as, for most inexpensive packages, the IPs are shared.